# Changing editor fonts in RAD Studio 2009

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

I can change the editor font in RAD Studio 2009 under the [Tools][Options] Editor Options/Display settings form, but the list of fonts is very limited and does not show all the installed fonts. Is there any way to add fonts to the selection ?

There is a work around by setting the font name in the registry, under [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\CodeGear\BDS\6.0\Editor\Options].

Comment: I'm pretty sure the list only contains fixed-width fonts. Which of yours do you think are missing?

Comment: Ok, fixed width only it is. I had not noticed that that was the common point between the fonts in the list. Cheers all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can only select fixed width fonts, so yes it is limited.  A good resource for some fonts to try is available at [Hivelogic](http://hivelogic.com/articles/top-10-programming-fonts).

Answer (score 4):

Fonts are fixed width.

I have good experience with these fonts:

- Courier New (default)
- Consolas
- Lucida Console

The last two are also great alternatives for Console fonts.

--jeroen

Comment: I personally prefer the DejaVu Sans Mono font.

Comment: DejaVu is nice, but I'm still addicted to Lucida Console since I got it somewhere in the Windows 3.x era :-)